# unable to send th data from servlet to jsp page in eclipse . how to solve this?

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

this part of servlet is creating problem to retrive the data.. i have made the changes which nick have mentioned below in the answer

HttpSession session = request.getSession();

```
            int id2= Integer.parseInt( null, rs2.getInt(1)); 


            String name2= rs2.getString(2);

            int age2=Integer.parseInt( null,rs2.getInt(3));

            String address2= rs2.getString(4);

            float percentage2 = Integer.parseInt( null,(int) rs2.getFloat(5));


           /* 
            session.setAttribute("name", rs2.getString(2));  
            session.setAttribute("id", rs2.getString(1));  
            session.setAttribute("address", rs2.getString(4));  
            session.setAttribute("percentage", rs2.getString(5)); 
            session.setAttribute("age", rs2.getString(3)); 

            */




           rows.add(row);

         }
        request.getSession().setAttribute("result", rows);  
        RequestDispatcher rd = getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher("/DDLResults.jsp");
        request.getRequestDispatcher("/next.jsp").include(request,response);

    }   catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        pw.println(e);
    }

}
```

}

Comment: utterly formatted :-( I do not see the problem description, stacktrace, anything ..

Comment: the problem is no data is being transferred to the jsp page.
A blank table is displayed on the browser. 
Plz help..!!

Comment: run time error :- java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "rows"    how to fix?

Comment: what error you getting, pls paste the stacktrace...

Comment: i have edited my servlet above. Tell me how should I should use parseInt properlt to remove numberformatexception.

Comment: I have already given you the answer.  You don't need to use parseInt at all. ResultSet.getInt() already returns the integer you want.

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#parseInt(java.lang.String) but you don't need this

Comment: Thanku Nick .. it finally worked. i learnt a lot from these types of servlet issues. thank you so much ..!! :)

Answer (score 1):

In your servlet, you have:

```
request.getSession().setAttribute("results", Rows);
```

But in your JSP, you have:

```
<c:forEach var="row" items="${result.rows}">
```

The name of the Session Attribute does not match. Change either the JSP or Servlet to use the same name, either `result` or `results`

EDIT:
each row is actually a `ArrayList<String>` so expressions like `${row.address}` will not work, because ArrayList does not have a getAddress method.

I recommend creating a new class like this:

```
public class Student {

  private int id;
  private String name;
  private String address;
  private int age;
  private int percentage;

  // getters and setters
}
```

In your Servlet, instead of

```
ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> Rows = new ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>();
```

have

```
ArrayList<Student> rows = new ArrayList<Student>();
```

Also in your Servlet, instead of

```
for (int i = 1; i <= 4; i++) {  
  row.add(rs2.getString(i));  
}
```

do this:

```
Student student = new Student();
student.setId(rs.getInt(1));
student.setName(rs.getString(2));
student.setAge(rs.getInt(3));
student.setAddress(rs.getString(4));
student.setPercentage(rs.getInt(5));
rows.add(student);
```

Comment: now i am getting a run time error   :-  java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "rows"

Comment: try `<c:forEach var="row" items="${result}">` instead

Comment: org.apache.jasper.JasperException: An exception occurred processing JSP page /next.jsp at line 28

Comment: <td><c:out value="${row.id}"/></td>  :- this is line 28

Comment: the problem is basically the number format in all the fields... plz help me to fix this trouble

Comment: There are more problems with this than I previously noticed. See amended answer above. Quite a lot of changes needed. It might not get you all the way there because I'm not running the code myself, but it should hopefully still help you.

Comment: m getting numberpoint exception. pls tell me how to use parseInt properly

Comment: Your code looks nothing like my suggestion. For example, `int id2= Integer.parseInt( null, rs2.getInt(1)); ` is certain to throw an exception. Can can you expect it format null as an integer? And you don't need to parse an String as an integer anyway. Why not just use resultSet.getInt()? that returns an integer.